# Python - File or Folder Content Version Control

Tags: python, django, version-control

We're using CKEditor to generate HTML content when author writes his book.  We're storing that content to a separate HTML file on the disk using python-django.

But now, we have got a requirement from client to show the history/revision  of the files (list of timestamps in a sidebar whenever author has pressed `ctrl+s`), like the Eclipse does:

[image]

I am planning to use diff by taking intersection of the html texts stored at 2 different times.

But I am not getting any idea about how to take the diff of images, audios and videos.

Any idea how git, eclipse or Vesrsion control systems do that?
Do they use any kind of encoding such as SHA to store it on the disk?

Please suggest if any other method I can use to do this.

I'm ready to use if any open source python lib available. I googled but no luck.

Comment: So, essentially,  are you looking to reimplement git?

Comment: @DeepSpace  Sort of, but we have to store it for a user session only like may be for max 4-6 hours and only for one HTML file. but you know HTML files may contain images, audio, video etc linked in it.

Comment: I don't think git can diff binary files. It can only *check* if the file has changed or not. For comparing files in Python see [filecmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html) module.

Comment: @Laxmikant: you want to save your files checksum? and SHA is not a encoding!! it is a hash! you can not reverse hashes to their original data!

Comment: i can write it for you.. you mean files checksums ( then you can compare them together, checksum : creation_time, modified_time, file_hash, size, path , ... ) ? or ...?

Comment: @DRPK - Answer it then ,I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This ( i wrote a Class for you ):

```
import os
import time
import hashlib


class SimpleFileCheckSum(object):

    def __init__(self, path):

        self.path = path
        self.output = {}

    def check_path_error(self):

        if os.path.exists(self.path) is True and os.path.isfile(self.path):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_file_size(self):

        try:
            st_data = os.stat(self.path)
            get_size = str(st_data.st_size)

        except PermissionError:

            try:

                os_size_data = str(os.path.getsize(self.path))
                self.output["SIZE"] = os_size_data

            except:
                self.output["SIZE"] = "Error"

        else:
            self.output["SIZE"] = get_size

    def get_file_times(self):

        def convert_time_to_human_readable(get_time):

            return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(get_time))

        try:

            my_st_object = os.stat(self.path)

            file_creation_time = convert_time_to_human_readable(my_st_object.st_ctime)
            file_last_modified_time = convert_time_to_human_readable(my_st_object.st_mtime)

        except:
            self.output['TIMES'] = {"CREATION": "Error", "MODIFIED": "Error"}

        else:
            self.output['TIMES'] = {"CREATION": file_creation_time, "MODIFIED": file_last_modified_time}

    def get_file_full_path(self):

        try:

            get_full_path = os.path._getfullpathname(self.path)
            get_final_path = os.path._getfinalpathname(self.path)

        except:
            self.output['PATH'] = {"FULL": "Error", "FINAL": "Error"}

        else:
            self.output['PATH'] = {"FULL": get_full_path, "FINAL": get_final_path}

    def get_file_hashes(self):

        try:

            hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
            hash_sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
            hash_sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
            hash_sha512 = hashlib.sha512()

            with open(self.path, "rb") as f:
                for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2 ** 20), b""):
                    hash_md5.update(chunk)
                    hash_sha1.update(chunk)
                    hash_sha256.update(chunk)
                    hash_sha512.update(chunk)

        except:
            self.output["HASH"] = {"MD5": "Error", "SHA1": "Error", "SHA256": "Error", "SHA512": "Error"}

        else:
            self.output["HASH"] = {"MD5": hash_md5.hexdigest(), "SHA1": hash_sha1.hexdigest(),
                                   "SHA256": hash_sha256.hexdigest(), "SHA512": hash_sha512.hexdigest()}

    def call_all(self):

        if self.check_path_error() is True:

            self.get_file_full_path()
            self.get_file_size()
            self.get_file_times()
            self.get_file_hashes()

            return self.output

        else:
            return {"Error": "Your Path is Not Valid"}


if __name__ == '__main__':

    file_info = SimpleFileCheckSum("Your_file_address")
    get_last_data = file_info.call_all()

    print("Your Raw Dict Output : ", get_last_data, "\n\n")
```

**NOTE:** so you can ask; if i have my file address, why i need get_file_full_path() sub function?... because you can put a dynamic address to this class like "./myfile" and get_file_full_path() will reaturn its full and final addresses.

Comment: Awesome, Many thanks...! +1 for `get_file_full_path`